# rake migration aborted: could not find table 'roles'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, abort

I just inherited code that I'm attempting to run the migrations for but I keep getting a rake aborted error.  I've come across others that have what appears to be similar issues, but most involved Heroku and I'm trying to run this locally (to start.)

I've tried troubleshooting using both PostgreSQL and SQLite, and both produce the same issue. The table "roles" referenced is the second migration called, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what is causing it to not get built.  Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Here's the roles migration:

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the trace for SQLite:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'roles'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:470:in `table_structure'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:351:in `columns'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:248:in `column_names'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:261:in `column_methods_hash'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:69:in `all_attributes_exists?'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:27:in `method_missing'
/Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/recprototype/config/initializ
ers/constants.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engi
ne.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engi
ne.rb:587:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engi
ne.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/appl
ication.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rail
tie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/recprototype/config/environme
nt.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/appl
ication.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/appl
ication.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:205:in `call'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:200:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:200:in `execute'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
 `mon_synchronize'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:174:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
 `mon_synchronize'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:144:in `invoke'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `
<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Here is the trace for PostgreSQL:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "roles" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"roles"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a
.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"roles"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1106:in `async_exec'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1106:in `exec_no_cache'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:649:in `exec_query'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1231:in `column_definitions'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:845:in `columns'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:248:in `column_names'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:261:in `column_methods_hash'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:69:in `all_attributes_exists?'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active
_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:27:in `method_missing'
/Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/recprototype/config/initializ
ers/constants.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engi
ne.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engi
ne.rb:587:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engi
ne.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/appl
ication.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rail
tie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/recprototype/config/environme
nt.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/appl
ication.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/appl
ication.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:205:in `call'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:200:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:200:in `execute'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
 `mon_synchronize'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:174:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
 `mon_synchronize'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb
:144:in `invoke'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/applica
tion.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `
<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Comment: What does the first migration do (before this migration)?

Comment: Are your migrations running in the right order? Try executing them manually with rake db:migrate VERSION=20098252345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that  `config/initializers/constants.rb` is doing something to the `Role` class that requires the roles table to be present. When you run migrations initialisers are loaded as normal, so your app blows up because the table doesn't exist yet.

It's likely that the developer that added this dependency on the roles table existing did so after the roles table was created on their machine.

You could

- try loading the schema instead of running migration `rake db:schema:load` assuming schema.rb was checked in. This won't work if loading the schema loads initialisers - I can't remember if this is the case
- restore the database from a SQL dump
- comment out the offending code (or bracket it with a test that the table exists), and run migrations/load schema - it's unlikely that whatever is being done is essential for running migrations. If commenting out that code produces more failures use source control to restore the app to the point such after the migration was initially checked in, where hopefully any such issues would be easier to untangle

Comment: Thanks.  I wound up commenting out the constants.rb code, then was able to run the migrations.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I'll post it as an answer anyways because I think it will help you.

Instead of running all of the code's migrations from the beginning of time, you should use the `schema.rb` file for the app. Note, this only works when you're first setting up an existing app that you've begun work on (because it force-creates all the tables, therefore deleting any content), but it is the correct way to load your database in this case. Migrations are meant for incremental changes.

To load the schema into your database:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Then your database will be setup according to the `schema.rb` file (which gets updated automatically by Rails for this exact purpose).

**Edit**
The cause of your problem is probably some code in your application getting loaded before the migration that references the `roles` table (or more likely the `Role` model). This happens frequently when there is a database query in the `routes.rb` file, but it could be from any number of files that get loaded when the `environment` rake task is invoked (which is the case for the `:migrate` task).

**Edit 2** Looking at your stack trace:

> /Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/recprototype/config/initializ
>   ers/constants.rb:1:in `'

I guess that the `config/initializers/constants.rb` file has something like `Role.all`. The initializers get loaded whenever the Rails environment is loaded (which is the case for most rake tasks provided by Rails).

You should still use the `rake db:schema:load` task, but you'll need to comment out that line before you run it (if my theory is correct, of course).